# Session not getting value from phtml to block class magento 2

Tags: magento2, session

Value get back from session.
did'nt get values please someone review my code.
need help

Here's my code:
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;




class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{

   /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */


       protected $_coreSession;

    protected $quoteValidator = null; 

     protected $vls = null;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator, \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession)
    {
    $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
       $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }



       public function getValue()
{
     $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMyValue(); //Get value from customer session
}



  public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);




    global $total_cost;
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setValue($total_cost); //set value in customer session
$vluas= $customerSession->getValue();

$this->vls = $vluas[0].$vluas[1];


    $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
    $fee = $this->vls; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
    $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

    $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

    $total->setFee($balance);
    $total->setBaseFee($balance);

    $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
    $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


    return $this;
    } 

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
    $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
    $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */



    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {



       global $total_cost;
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setValue($total_cost); //set value in customer session
$vluas= $customerSession->getValue();

$this->vls = $vluas[0].$vluas[1];
//print_r($vls);

    return [
        'code' => 'fee',
        'title' => 'Shipping Price',
        'value' => $this->vls
    ];

    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
    return __('Fee');
    }
}
```

/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping */ ?>

<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": true}}'>
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
    <strong id="block-shipping-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQuote()->isVirtual() ? __('Estimate Tax') : __('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?>
    </strong>
    </div>
    <div id="block-summary" data-bind="scope:'block-summary'" class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-shipping-heading">

    <?php

 global $total_cost;
  global $value1;
$total_vendor_cost;

$this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
$themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('mr_dukaaniatest');
$sql = "select * from  $themeTable ";
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);


foreach ($result as $results)

    //echo 'Value 1: ' .
    $value1 = $results['title'];
    echo '</br>';
    //echo 'Value 2: ' .
    $value2 = $results['author'];
// echo '</br>';




?>  
                <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?php ?></span></th>

                <?php


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

 $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $itemname =  $item->getProductId();

    echo 'ID: '.
     $item->getProductId()
     //.'<br />';
    // echo "<br />";            

  ?>
                 <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?php  ?></span></th>

                 <?php



}

$themeTable1 = $this->_resources->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar');
$sql1 = "SELECT count(DISTINCT value) from  $themeTable1 where attribute_id=166 and entity_id = $itemname ";

$entities = $connection->fetchAll($sql1);

//$entity_name =  $entities['count'];
//var_dump($entity_name);


foreach ($entities as $row)
 echo 'Vendor Count: ' .
    $vendor_count = $row['count(DISTINCT value)'];
   echo '</br>';

    if($vendor_count > 1)
    {

     $vendor_counts = ($vendor_count - 1);

     $values_1 = $vendor_counts * $value2;

     $total_cost = $values_1 +$value1;

    echo 'Extra Fee Cost Total: '.
    $total_cost;
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Extra Fee Cost: '.
       $total_cost = $value1;
    }

   // $entity_name =  $entity['value'];

    //var_dump($entities);








use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface as CoreSession;

class MyClass
{
     protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ){
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}





public function setValue($total_cost){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    $this->_coreSession->setMyValue($total_cost);

}




}




?>




    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#block-summary": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBaseUrl() ?>');
        })
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use **\Magento\Framework\Session\Generic** class for default session,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $session
    )  {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->_coreSession->getMyValue(); //Get value from customer session
    }

    public function setValue($total_cost)
    {
        return $this->_coreSession->setMyValue($total_cost);
    }
```

Comment: first time it shows me my default value that i set then it after another refresh it change it to 0

Comment: @rakesh I have followed the same concept but I am unable to retrieve on another page could you please help me on it. i am setting data on home page but unable to retrive on cart pages

Comment: Yes i have been facing same issue @jhonjhondoe do u have fix for this. could you please share me